# Why isnt the rowheight being changed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, grand-central-dispatch

The console logs the correct row height how ever the correct row height is not being displayed in the tableview correctly. ImageURLS is a string array containing download imageURLS from Firebase Storage.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Reuse", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    ///////////////////////

    let downloadURL = URL(string: self.imageURLS[indexPath.row]) 
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL!) { (data, _, _) in
        if let data = data {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.cellImageView.image = image
                cell.cellImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                let aspectRatio = Float((cell.cellImageView?.image?.size.width)!/(cell.cellImageView?.image?.size.height)!)
                print("aspectRatio: \(aspectRatio)")
                tableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)/aspectRatio)
              print("tableView.rowHeight: \(tableView.rowHeight)")
            }
        }
        }.resume()


    ///////////////////////
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the `UITableView rowHeight` property? It's not what you need.

Comment: @rmaddy what do I need? I'm reading that there are performance implications for using a `optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` which would limit scalability beyond 1000 rows.

Comment: If you want each row to have a different height then you need to implement the `heightForRowAt` delegate.

Comment: @rmaddy is there a solution that avoids the performance limitations that using `heightForRowAt` would entail. [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview)

Comment: Don't worry about any possible performance until you actually have a performance issue.